# Help choosing the right data structure

Tags: c#, java, data-structures

I need a data structure with the following requirements:

1. Needs to be able to get elements by index (like a List).
2. I will always just add / remove elements from the end of the structure.

I am inclined to use an `ArrayList`. In this situation, it seems to be `O(1)` both to read elements (they always are?), remove elements (I only need to remove them at the end of the list) and to add(I only add to the end of the list).

There is only the problem that time to time the ArrayList will have a performance penalty when it's completly full and I need to add more elements to it.

Is there any other better idea? I don't think of a data structure that'd beat the `ArrayList` here.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds good, though in C# you should use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). It's the Java equivalent of [`ArrayList<E>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The `ArrayList` class in C# is not generic and is basically made obsolete by the new `List<T>` class.

> There is only the problem that time to time the ArrayList will have a performance penalty when it's completely full and I need to add more elements to it.

This probably won't be a problem and you probably shouldn't worry about it unless you've performance profiled. However if you know (or can guess) in advance the number of elements that your list will contain you can set its [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) to that value ([`ensureCapacity`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) in Java). This will cause the list to reserve the required memory in advance. You can also give the capacity to the list constructor in [both](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) [languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use an ArrayList.

This will dynamically resize when it hits its capacity limit as you rightly say. However this should not be a problem as it does so using a sufficiently clever algorithm that the average cost per append operation is still only O(1).

Answer (score 0):

always use `List<T>` instead of ArrayList

Comment: No, wrong! You haven't understood the question. The point is that the questioner wants to know which of the concrete Java implementations of List<T> he should actually use.

If this was about C# then I'll take the downvote back.

Comment: yep, this was just only for C# :) Who uses Java anyways? :)

Comment: Yes, I should have taken notice in advance that Java and C# implementations/names are different :(

Comment: So your post was meant to read "use C# instead of Java"? Downvote for pointless religious war.

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding is probably more O(N)  as the array must be reallocated and copied when it grows over the allocation limits. The Javadocs specify it grows at a amortized cost of O(N) whatever that means, as I would expect O(NlogN) but apparently they have smarter algorithms than I am aware of.

It is O(1) if you allocate enough elements to contain the complete colleciton at construction time.

see : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: While a full array allocation is O(N) the amortised cost is only O(1) per addition. They do this by growing the array with an exponential scale factor (which means that full reallocations happen exponentially less often)

Answer (score 0):

You need to balance the relative frequency of your read access versus your write access to the [`List<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html). It must be noted that for most uses it is unlikely that you will notice the cost of resizing an [`ArrayList<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

However if you are adding and removing items one at time at the end as you say more than you will be getting items by index (basically using the List as a [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) or [Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29)) and your profiler tells you that [`ArrayList<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is where your performance bottleneck is, you should consider using a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which is intended for just this sort of usage.

Comment: Both read and write operations are slow on a LinkedList for accessing the last element. With a Double Linked List it's a different story, though.